# Not getting actual page numbers in table of content

Tags: table-of-contents

I am writing my thesis. As per my thesis, abbreviation takes 2 pages which start from (iii), so that next section in table of content acknowledgement should start from (v) number, and abstract start from (vi).

But in the following image shows incorrect page numbers appearance on these stated sections.

> My code sample is

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\clearpage\pagenumbering{roman}
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}
\chapter*{Abbreviations}
{2 page of abbreviations}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgement} 
\chapter*{Acknowledgement}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong page numbers in toc]

Comment: Write x before your \addcontentsline commands, to get       a feeling on which page they are executed.

Comment: If you didn't got what Ulrike says ... add the `\addcontentsline` after the sectioning command and not before that....

Comment: @koleygr Yes. I tried that one. It works for me, thank you so much

Comment: @UlrikeFischer ... Please turn your comment into an answer in order to be able to close the question as answered (solved). Welcome limlian